# How to run parallel computation for several independent tasks

Tags: r, foreach, snow

I want to use the snow or do snow run different tasks in parallel. Each task can be a piece of codes which are totally independent to each other. Below is a example 3 independent tasks

```
#### # task 1: simply assign a value
a<-1:100;
#### # task 2: run a regression model
f1<-lm(b~c); 
#### # task 3: subsetting a data
d<-subset(d, ACCT_ID>100);
```

My solution is:

```
My.Tasks <-function(id,x,y) {
if(id==1){a<-1:100;return(a)}
if(id==2){f1<-lm(b~c);return(f1)
if(id==3){d<-subset(d, ACCT_ID>100);return(d)}
}
cl <- makeCluster(3,type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
system.time(test<-foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% {My.Tasks(i)})
stopCluster(cl)
```

I'm just trying to explore the possibility of having more flexibility of running a list of expressions. like runining a list of regression model, where the model form and data might not be consistently formated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.  The general guideline on this forum is that if you are asking for code help you should show what you have tried thus far and what has not worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

It is bit awkward to execute unrelated R expressions in parallel with snow or doSNOW, but you can do it by creating a list of unevaluated expressions using the `quote` function.  You then evaluate these expressions on the cluster workers via the `eval` function.  Here's an example of that using foreach and doSNOW:

```
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(3)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
d <- data.frame(ACCT_ID=1:110, x=rnorm(110))
c <- 1:10
b <- 3*c + 13
x <- list(quote(1:100), quote(lm(b~c)), quote(subset(d, ACCT_ID > 100)))
r <- foreach(y=x, .export=c('b', 'c', 'd')) %dopar% {
  eval(y)
}
a <- r[[1]]
f1 <- r[[2]]
d <- r[[3]]
```

Note that it doesn't make much sense to include the assignments in the task expressions.  You evaluate the expressions in parallel and the resulting values are returned in a list which the example assigns to the variable `r` and then assigns to the desired variables.

Also note that this simple example doesn't take anywhere near enough time to warrant executing in parallel.  I wouldn't bother unless the individual tasks took at least 10 seconds and the entire computation took at least five minutes.

Comment: Thanks Steve, your solution is really similar to what I think of. But the quote and the eval is really I should further look into. Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private async Task ParallelComputation()
{
    Task[] taskArray = new Task[]
    {
       Task.Run(() =>
       {
           PlaceSomeCodeInComputationMethod1();
       }),
       Task.Run(() =>
       {
           PlaceSomeCodeInComputationMethod2();
       })
    };
    await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
}
```

Thanks to "async Task" user interface will not be blocked (if any).

Comment: Not sure what language your answer is in, but the question is tagged `R`. My apologies if the tag has been updated since your response.

Comment: It is c#, no problem :)